# Best data structure to use

Tags: list, algorithm, data-structures, tree, heap

The problem is: I have an input of strings, every line of text is ordered 1,2,3,4,5... I have to put these strings inside every line, for example, if the input is

```
"1.Hi john 2. How are you? 3. XXXX 4.TTTTT"
```

The output will be:

```
(1)Hi john 
(2) How are you? 
(3) XXXX 
(4)TTTTT
```

I can't have an input of row 7, if row 5 and 6 aren't already filled.
In input I have also some command, for example:

- print line 3
- change line 2 with a given string
- delete line 3 (and the next lines will upscale, so 4 becomes 3, 5 becomes 4...)
- undo
- redo

Which is the best data structure to implement? I started with a heap, because everything is ordered, but if I delete a node, I need to push every next lines up, and I have some problems with heaps. I also thought about persistent tree, because I need to remember precedent step to be able to do the undo and redo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer primarily depends on which operations you want to optimize on.

1. Array - access is quickest.  So it will optimize on printline and change line.
2. Double Ended Linked List - access anywhere apart from head and tail needs traversal.  However, it can easily handle your delete, undo and redo situations.

For your undo and redo function, you should create a separate undo stack, where you store the removed or changed nodes, together with its old state.  Redo is a matter of popping elements off the stack to reapply them into the main list.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to be adding and deleting lines a lot, and you also expect to be referring to lines by their (current) index, what you want is an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). This is a type of binary tree which, in addition to normal binary tree operations (including efficient insertion and deletion), allows you to efficiently access items by index. In this case, it's not a binary *search* tree because you don't have a sort key; all of your accesses will be by (current) index.

In order to efficiently support undo/redo, you would additionally make the tree into a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), using "path copying" to partially modify the data while still allowing access to the old version of it. (Path copying would be ideal for order-statistic trees, since all your updates propagate to the root anyway.) Undo would simply be reverting to that old version.

But: Unless you are dealing with *millions or billions of lines*, these weird exotic data structures are not going to be worth your time. So while the literal answer is "persistent order-statistic tree" the practical answer is "probably just put stuff in an array, and have a stack of undo operations to support undo/redo".

Comment: But how do i implement the tree? I receive the strings in order, so 1,2,3,4.... How can i make a tree? I think that it will become a list in the end, can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of a Map and Double Link List.

**Double Link List** : Where actual string will be stored, and the index of node will represent number of corresponding string.

Ex-> Print line 3, you print 3rd node in this list

**Map** : Here key will be the line no, and value will be the corresponding references to Double link list. This will help in insertion and deletion of a new string in Link List.

Ex -> Delete line 3, find the reference of line 3 DLL node from map, change the references in DLL and remove line 3 node. Similar process for update and insertion of a line.

For Undo and Redo as @John advised, you can use 2 different stacks, 1 reflecting the operations done (which will help in undo), and 1 reflecting the undo operations (which will help in redo operation).

Comment: I thought of indexing the list with a Map too, but it won't work.  Let's say you have list 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. What do you do when you delete 3?  You can seek 2 through the map and delete 3 in the list.  But now what?  You have 1, 2, 3, 4 in the list and 1, 2, 4, 5 in the map.  You need to reindex the map.  This is more expensive than linear traversal through the list, hence pointless.

Comment: You re right @John, didnt think of that scenario.Do you know how to downvote your own answer ?